# How to save a definition in one file and update it easily?

Tags: variable-definitions, save

When running a task which needs a long time for computation but returns a simple result, I often do this:

```
temp = (*some computation*);
Import["re.wl"]; (*there is some definition in "re.wl"*)
re[1] = temp;
Export["re.wl", Definition[re]];
```

`"re.wl"` may be:

```
re[1] = 1;
re[2] = 2;
```

In this way I can update `re[1]` in `"re.wl"` without recalculating `re[2]`.

What I want is to wrap this code, so I wrote this:

```
(*syms is symbols that need to be stored*)
Module[{cachepath = FileNameJoin[ParentDirectory[path], "DefinitionCache.wl"]},
        cachepath = Export[cachepath, Definition[syms], OverwriteTarget->"KeepBoth"];
        Import[path];
        Import[cachepath];(*new definition in cachepath will overwrite old definition*)
        Export[path, Definition[syms]];
        DeleteFile[cachepath];
    ];
```

I create a cache file because I don't know how to "save" the definition in memory so I save it in storage. I'm not satisfied with this so I'm wondering how to make a copy of a symbol's definition.

Is there a better to refresh the definition in the file without redundant calculation?

Thanks creidhne for helping me check for grammatical errors!

Answer (score 0):

You could use "DownValues" to store your values. E.g.:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
re[1] = a;
dv = DownValues[re]

{HoldPattern[re[1]] :> a}

re[2] = b;
dv = DownValues[re]

{HoldPattern[re[1]] :> a, HoldPattern[re[2]] :> b}
```

If you later want the value of e.g. "re[2]" and re[2] is not available because it is overwritten or cleared, you may write:

```
re[2]=.
re[2] /. dv

b
```

Comment: Daniel, please explain, if I understand it right. I guess that this definition is only saved within the present session, is it? Or you mean that it can be retrieved in the course of the next session?

Comment: This is only saved in the present session. If you want to store it, you may use e.g.: "DumpSave" and "Get"

Comment: Thanks, but compared to `DownValues`, I think `Definition` is more helpful. `Definition` contains more information, and when a file generated by `Export[_, Definition[_]]` is imported, the definitions will be automatically loaded. What really confuses me is that `Definition` returns nothing but just print something therefore I cannot use a temporary variable(like `dv` in your answer) to store the old definitions in the memory, so I need to create the cache file. Of course `DownValues` is enough to store `re` in my question, but I still want to ask if there is a way I can use `Definition`.

Comment: I think your out of luck. From the help: "Definition is an output form; it does not evaluate"

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Or maybe I can manually convert the DownVaules to Definition form. In document I found this: "Definition[symbol] prints as all values, attributes, defaults and options for symbol", does that means I only need to store `DownValues`, `UpValues`, `OwnValues`, `SubValues`, `Options`, `Attributes` and `DefaultValues`, then I can get all the information about a Symbol?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.